# Does my ISP have a clue about what type of activity I'm doing on WhatsApp/Viber/Telegram?

Tags: whatsapp, isp, voip

Can my ISP see the difference between sending messages, making video call, and simply engaging with communities - building on traffic types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can. A message is a few bytes, hardly one kilobyte, while a video call can be several MB of traffic.

They cannot see who you are talking to, or what community you are engaged with, but they can know the kind of activity.